# Bitrise bash script - command not found

Tags: bash, deployment, bitrise, sips

i am building an android project with Bitrise.
i am running a bash script that resize the app icon with "sips" command.
locally everything is working fine, but when i am running on Bitrise build i got an error:
./Android/android-icons-generator.sh: line 32: **sips: command not found**

any idea why the sips command is not found?
thanks for your help !!

Comment: Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: Isn't `sips` a macOS only (actually BSD) tool? Even if it's available on Linux it's not preinstalled on Ubuntu (`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash -c 'which sips'` indicates it's not installed). This post recommends `convert` as a Linux alternative: https://techblog.willshouse.com/2013/02/18/what-is-the-sips-equivalent-in-linux-unix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are building locally using macOS and on Bitrise you are building on Linux. As Viktor says in his comment the "sips" command is not available on Linux. You could solve this one of two ways:

1. Use a cross platform tool for image resizing (ImageMagick is a popular option) and make sure that is installed as part of your build.
2. Switch to using the Hybrid stack on Bitrise which provides macOS with the Android tooling installed.